# PCIe - SATA bridge/host controller ICs unavailable to the hobbyist/from low volume suppliers?

Tags: integrated-circuit, components, pcie, bridge, sata

I was toying with the idea of a project that would involve adding a SATA device to an existing PCIe lane; probably far too ambitious for me, but before I could confirm that I noticed that there aren't *any* PCIe-SATA bridges available from suppliers like Digikey, Mouser, Element14.

There are PCIe/SATA redrivers & muxes, and PCIe-USB bridges, and USB-SATA bridges, but not PCIe-SATA bridges. Such chips exist (e.g JMB58x) but are not available anywhere that I'm aware of that an individual/someone ordering low volume might be able to use.

Am I misunderstanding some terminology? My best guess was that it's just too specialised/high speed, unavailable because nobody/org that can't 'call for pricing' etc. would be capable of using it anyway - but then surely that would equally apply to redrivers and muxes, and to PCIe-USB bridges for that matter.

Comment: You're looking for a "host bus adapter", not a "bridge", as the accesses aren't transparent.

Comment: Another option to consider: buy a cheap PCIe to SATA card and harvest the chip.  If you only need a one-off, that might work well enough, and you have a known good design to look at

Answer (score 1):

SATA is quite an old standard.

NVMe drives are [directly connected to the PCI-E](https://www.kingston.com/france/en/community/articledetail/articleid/48543#:%7E:text=NVMe%20was%20designed%20for%20SSD,independent%20of%20storage%20form%20factor.&text=NVMe%20technology%20is%20available%20in,2.) bus for speed reasons and do not need any chip to interface them to it.

Perhaps use some NVMe drives instead of SATA and you won't face this issue.

Comment: For this particular case it was to use spinning platter disk I wanted to use, (for price/capacity, already having some) but also interested more generally as e.g. CD/DVD/BD drives still use SATA too.

Comment: Indeed in that case you might be out of luck. You may be able to implement that in an FPGA with PCI-E & Sata IP, but that would be quite some significant work. Perhaps use a SATA-USB chip instead. You can still find those PCIe-SATA bridges from some shady reseller but might be risky.